# Как правильно установить z-index, чтобы был виден элемент?

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы `.child` был виден, т.е. находился по слоям выше всех. При этом не убирать свойство z-index у `.two` и не менять структуру html

```css
.one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 20
}

.two  {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top:50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 30
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>

<div class="two">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Родительский индекс в приоритете, получается... https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/b2kqdh5x/ - разве что поставить one внутри two, чтобы они уже внутри договорились между собой...

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя. Если у родительского элемента установлен `z-index`, то дочерние элементы не могут быть выше или ниже этого уровня.

`z-index` родителя задаёт так называемый "контекст наложения". В вашем случае элементы `.one` и `.two` накладываются друг на друга относительно контекста их родителя. А элемент `.child` находится в контексте `.two`. И изменение свойства `z-index` у `.child` будет менять его позицию только относительно других элементов внутри `.two`.